# Difference between "so rude" and "too rude"

Tags: usage

What's different between

> You are **so** rude.

and

> You are **too** rude.

I want to know difference in grammar, social communication, rigor, manner and where they are used! (other things as well).

Comment: The phrase _so rude_ simply means “very rude”, while _too rude_ means “more rude than you should be”.

Comment: @J.R. You should make that an answer. Nobody can say better.

Comment: @SovereignSun - A lot more could be said in a good answer. The OP asked for differences in social communication and rigor as well as meaning; my answer doesn't touch on those aspects at all.

Comment: @J.R. Thanks again. If my question is ridicule or stupid for people, I prefer to delete it now!

Comment: @MyGlasses - I don’t think it’s a foolish question at all! It’s an interesting question. Maybe you haven’t received an answer because it’s kind of challenging to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both **so** and **too** have several meanings. Used as in your examples, the definitions of these words in the Cambridge Dictionary are:

> [**so**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/so) = very, extremely, or to such a degree:
>
> - The house is **so** beautiful.
> - Thank you for being **so** patient.
>
> [**too**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/too) = very, or completely:
>
> - My mother hasn't been **too** well recently.
> - (formal) Thank you, you're **too** kind.

The main difference between them is the strength of the message:

- **so**  = very
- **too** = excessively, beyond expectations

Bottom line: **too** is stronger than **so** in these examples.